# Spark application using java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

I'm new on spark and I have an application with java language , I'm tring to reprogram it on spark using java laguage. I have a fucntion coded in java :

```
 public boolean isbetween(Date date, Date start, Date end) {
    try {
        if (!date.before(start) && !date.after(end)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to reprogram this function on spark.

I have two DataSet :

```
+-------+-------------------+
|    nom|         date_track|
+-------+-------------------+
|record1|2020-02-13 14:53:08|
|record2|2020-02-18 15:25:03|
|record3|2020-02-20 10:11:03|
|record4|2020-02-19 10:23:43|
|record5|2020-02-19 11:23:03|
|record6|2019-02-19 14:21:54|
|record7|2020-02-30 10:14:54|
|record8|2020-02-25 10:17:41|
+-------+-------------------+
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|     nom|         start_date|           end_date|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
| record9|2020-02-18 14:53:07|2020-02-18 18:53:07|
|record10|2020-02-19 10:25:03|2020-02-19 14:25:03|
|record11|2020-02-19 10:24:03|2020-02-19 16:24:03|
|record12|2020-02-19 10:23:43|2020-02-19 20:23:43|
|record13|2020-02-19 10:23:03|2020-02-19 17:23:03|
|record14|2020-02-19 10:21:54|2020-02-19 21:21:54|
|record15|2020-02-19 10:18:54|2020-02-19 15:18:54|
|record16|2020-02-19 10:17:54|2020-02-19 19:17:54|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I tried the following code to do what's in the function

```
  DF1.join(DF2.filter(!functions.col("date_track").lt("start_date") ) && (!functions.col("date_track").gt("end_date")));
```

but it doesn't work . If you have any idea to ho do that help me.